# Drupal Content Admins for specific Language

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n

For a new Project with Drupal 7 we have 4 different languages: IT, AT, EN, SP and for each language an Content Admin. We need a solution that the Content Admin see only Nodes of his language for editing. Is there a module or how to implement it?